# How can I use Python to inspect the complete raw HTML data on the clipboard?

Tags: python, clipboard

I have a simple python app that uses pywin32 to inspect the raw clipboard. The content on the clipboard is HTML content with JSON data formatting. I'm able to successfully traverse the JSON path to pull the data out that I'm looking for.

The issue is, it works great on my local machine. But, when I deploy it to fly.io, fly can't seem to find the pywin32 module in it's repository.

Is there any other way to inspect the raw clipboard using any other language that would be easy to deploy to a service like fly.io?

Here's the relevant portion of my code that extracts the raw clipboard data as HTML.

```
def get_clipboard_html_windows():
    try:
        result = subprocess.run(
            ["powershell", "get-clipboard", "-Raw", "-TextFormatType", "Html"],
            capture_output=True,
            text=True
        )
        if result.returncode == 0:
            return result.stdout
        else:
            print("Failed to get clipboard content.")
            return None
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error:", e)
        return None
```

Is there an alternative approach I should consider using packages that are more open and available?

Please note that I am not looking for a simple clipboard paste tool. I've tried those and they do not actually return the RAW clipboard data. Here's an example of the data that's on the clipboard that I'm retrieving. In this example, simple tools would only return the "Long Position" value.

```
Version:0.9
StartHTML:0000000105
EndHTML:0000002269
StartFragment:0000000141
EndFragment:0000002233
<html>
<body>
<!--StartFragment--><meta charset="utf-8"><span data-tradingview-clip="{"sources":[{"type":"drawing","geometry":[{"x":0.5748417416493814,"y":0.5668696585616829},{"x":0.843941973328565,"y":0.5866510137377625},{"x":0.5848084168967586,"y":0.5668696585616829}],"source":{"type":"LineToolRiskRewardLong","id":"8ImQrp","state":{"linecolor":"rgba(120, 123, 134, 1)","linewidth":1,"textcolor":"#ffffff","fontsize":12,"fillLabelBackground":true,"labelBackgroundColor":"#585858","fillBackground":true,"stopBackground":"rgba(240, 98, 146, 0.2)","profitBackground":"rgba(0, 151, 167, 0.2)","stopBackgroundTransparency":80,"profitBackgroundTransparency":80,"drawBorder":false,"borderColor":"#667b8b","compact":true,"riskDisplayMode":"money","accountSize":100000,"lotSize":1,"risk":200,"alwaysShowStats":false,"showPriceLabels":true,"symbolStateVersion":2,"zOrderVersion":2,"visible":true,"frozen":false,"symbol":"CME_MINI:NQU2022","currencyId":"USD","unitId":null,"title":"Long","interval":"5","stopLevel":138,"profitLevel":461,"riskSize":200,"qty":0.2898550724637681,"amountTarget":100668.12,"amountStop":99800},"points":[{"time_t":1658339400,"offset":0,"price":12391},{"time_t":1658347500,"offset":0,"price":12380.25},{"time_t":1658339700,"offset":0,"price":12391}],"zorder":-31250,"ownerSource":"_seriesId","linkKey":"lFoFCzGlnuHJ","sharingMode":1,"version":2},"modelId":"8061dbf3-d808-49d8-93cf-b290890308be"}],"title":"Long Position"}">Long Position</span><!--EndFragment-->
</body>
</html>
```